# Count variable never resetting

Tags: java, loops, count

I have a function for creating an ArrayList of average values to plot on a graph, it looks like:

```
public void setupAverageEntries(int everyNthTimeStamp){
    this.avgEntries = new ArrayList<GraphEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.getTimeStampData().size() - everyNthTimeStamp; i += everyNthTimeStamp) {

        int avgVolume = new Integer(0);
        int total = new Integer(0);

        for (int j = 0; j < i + everyNthTimeStamp; j ++) {
            total += data.getVolumeData().get(j);
        }

        avgVolume = total / everyNthTimeStamp; // get the average volume over a certain amount of time stamps

        System.out.println("TOTAL " + total);
        System.out.println("AVG " + avgVolume);

        Point p = new Point(i + everyNthTimeStamp / 2, avgVolume); // plot a point with the average volume and in the middle of the NthTimeStamp
        GraphEntry avgE = new GraphEntry(p, avgVolume, i + everyNthTimeStamp / 2);
        this.avgEntries.add(avgE);
    }
}
```

I would have thought that initialising 'total' in the first loop to 0 would mean that it would reset after the second loop is finished using it to calculate the 'avgVolume', but the output it produces shows me that total is only ever incremented. I thought it might be a referencing problem but even after declaring 'total' and 'avgVolume' new, total is still never reset.

Please help! Is it a scope related problem? Hopefully im not just being a blind bat...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's reset properly but in the inner loop you always iterate on the same data, just going further in each run of the inner loop than in the previous. So it is natural that total is always greater than in the previous iteration.

I didn't analyze your code further but my guess is that the inner loop should start from i instead of 0.

Comment: Ahhhh! The initialisation of the inner loop needs to be int j = i; so that the second loop follows along behind the first. Thank you!

Comment: Meanwhile I extended the answer and that was my guess. :)